Chrome/Chromium/Edge/Teams Crashing when plugging in FIDO key
We are experimenting with FIDO2 keys to satisfy security controls and running into an issue where any Chromium-based application crashes immediately upon adding the device to Windows (not getting to a point where the authentication process happens)
I've tried examining the dump file in windbg and have submitted a Chromium bug report. I've tried different vendor keys as well.
Windbg points me to a specific line in component.cc but at this point I'm over my head. I suppose Teams v2 is crashing due to its integration with Edge Webview 2.
